# Remove white space between ion-nav-bar and ion-content in angular -meteor

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am trying to create a hybrid application in angular-meteor. I have included ionic packages too. I am getting a white thin line between ion-nav-bar and ion-content, but I am unable to understand the reason.

This is my index.html file

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title>Meteor</title>
</head>

<body>
<ion-nav-bar class="bar custom-dark">
    <ion-nav-back-button>
    </ion-nav-back-button>
</ion-nav-bar>
<ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>

</body>
```

this is my navigation.scss file. I tried to add padding and margin `0 !important` but it does not work.

```
.custom-dark{
  color : #0A2D3C !important; // text
  background-color:#0A2D3C!important; // for bg color
  margin: 0!important;
  padding: 0!important;
}
```

this is my forgotpassword file

```
<ion-view>
    <div class="bar bar-header">
        <button class="button button-icon icon ion-navicon"></button>
        <div class="h1 title">Header Buttons</div>
        <button class="button button-clear button-positive">Edit</button>
    </div>
    <ion-content class="background-image" padding="true">
        <h2 class="view-header-title">FORGOT PASSWORD</h2>
        <div class="div-full-width">
            <span  class="textfield-title">Please enter your email id to reset your password</span>
            <input id="email" class="textfields textfield-login" type="email"  placeholder="Enter email address" required>
            <input class="buttons loginButton" ng-click="forgot.clickOnConfirm()" type="button" value="CONFIRM">
        </div>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Comment: Where is the screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

Can you show the screenshot ? or try to reset margin and padding of

> ion-nav-back-button